# A word for someone who hurts the chances of others getting help

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice

There is a girl who would look for sympathy and attention over her mental health and by doing this made mental health issues and those suffering from mental health issues look like jokes. She damaged the chances of people getting help and cheapened the situations of others. I'm looking for a word to describe someone whose actions do this.

Answer (score 1):

***[Bad apple](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+bad+apple)*** might fit. The term originally meant one rotten member spoils all those around them, but recently it's been used to refer to one bad member of a group (often police officers) who makes them all look bad.

I've also heard such a person called a **spoiler**, or people would say this person **"spoiled it for the rest of us"**.